# Can I create a .xls file programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, xls, createfile

I need to create a .xls file from the Array data programmatically in iPhone. How can this be done?

Comment: Do you really need a .xls file or can a .csv file do the job for you?

Comment: Thnx for the reply. Here I need the data to be stored in .xls file and to display it and send it as an attachment to mail.

Comment: I want to create a .xls file with both image and text in iphone programatically. Did you  achieve it. what is the right approach to achieve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're in trouble, maybe not. The "old" xls format is a binary one and I am not aware of any free libraries which are able to read or write to that format. If this one is required, you're propably out of luck.

If however a more recent format will do you're back in business, because you can use xml (objc wrappers for lib2xml are readily available). Wikipedia features a short overwiev of the format which you might want to check out: [Excel file formats on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel#File_formats)